# Form-View Mapping Issue in Django

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-3.x

This is becoming very frustrating, like all of my Django form endeavors have been thus far...

I have a search bar form that is supposed to send the user to a url `'/project/search/<query>/'` and the url works fine if I type in a url but my form is not mapping correctly. I am implementing this first in the search results page, which will still have a search bar, and whenever I type in a value to the search bar I get redirected to '/project/search/'. Where have I gone wrong? I have spent a solid two days on this to no avail.

I am really struggling with this and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I wish I had at least an error or something to fix but this is just not working.

Here is my form class and view:

```
    from django import forms

    class SearchForm(forms.Form):
        search_string = forms.CharField(initial='Search Article Text',max_length=100)

def search(request, search_query):  

form = SearchForm()
context = RequestContext(request)
search_string = search_query.replace('_',' ')
search_terms = search_query.split('_')
search_results = Article.objects.all()
for term in search_terms:
    search_results = search_results.filter(article__icontains=term)

context_dict = {
    'search_string':search_string,
    'search_results':search_results,
    'form':form,
    }


if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    context_dict['form'] = form
    if form.is_valid():
        search_string = form.cleaned_data['search_string']
        search_query = search_string.replace(' ','_')
        ###return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search', args=(search_query,)))
        search_url = '/project/search/' + search_query + '/'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(search_url)
return render_to_response('search.html', context_dict, context)
```

The html:

```
<form action='/beacon/search/' class="navbar-form navbar-right" method='POST'>
              <div class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.search_string }}
              </div>
              <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-default'/>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after troubleshooting for probably 5 or so days I have realized what my issue was (I also had a little help from the Django Users Google group).

I am answering this in case anybody also has my problem in the future btw. I'm obviously not an expert on the forms part of Django.

This all had to do with the actual HTML writeup I had. In my form tag the action was to '/project/search/' which just redirected me to that URL because django thought /project/search/ was different than project/search/query  . Therefore all I needed to do for this part was change the action to refer to any URL that would validate my search view- so I picked /project/search/search_query/ but anything after /project/search/ would have worked.

My second issue was with my input. I needed to include a name in my input -'search_string'- so my search view would understand what values the form itself was carrying.

Therefore my html in the end looks like:

```
<form action='/beacon/search/search_query/' class="navbar-form navbar-right" method='POST'>
              <div class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name='search_string' class="form-control" placeholder="Search Article Text"/>
              </div>
              <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value='Submit'>Submit</button>-->
              <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-default'/>
            </form>
```

Credit to Branko Majic to helping my on Dj Users Group as well. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question. You're getting redirected because that's what you've told the view to do: you explicitly return an HttpResponseRedirect. If you don't want to redirect, don't do that.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change that from when I was just checking for a debug. Anyways the button redirects me to /project/search/ not /project/search/<query>. I'll put the code as how it was initially but it still was resulting in a redirect to /project/search/